# Why are people so fast hitting the downvote or close button on certain questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, downvotes

In some cases for me it seems like downvotes and the closure of a question (the latter is the more harsh thing to happen) come just too fast for certain types of questions where a little understanding would have helped a lot more.

For an example here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958425/how-to-create-this-program#comment40648771_25958425
Well, by the question's wording it quite obviously smells of "homework" all the way, but please take a look at the comments. Probably the asker was simply not an English native and couldn't appropriately phrase that he would like some hints on how to start solving this.

For those who would say he should have asked the professor or something along this line, I can reassure you (if you are lucky to lack such experience) in certain parts of the world, university professors who don't give a flick about what happens to the students, exist, and are quite demoralizing. It can happen you only get a sheet of 30 questions to complete in the semester, with no appropriate training, whatsoever. (I finished university three years ago, so this is *not* ranting about my current problems, just explaining the situations others may experience, by own experiences gathered five, six, seven or maybe even more years ago.)

Another example of fast closing I would have liked to link to was removed since. There someone from India asked apparently about parsing, but having poor English it was very unclear without looking in the reference link he provided. I carefully examined the thing and tried to respond him, just to face with the all-of-sudden darkened "Answer question" button for a storm of "close it"'s.

I think downvotes are okay, and they don't harm the asker except than demoralizing him for the sloppy question or sloppy manner of asking. But why close stuff without them having a chance to get even some hints of what to do?

Seriously, what the heck motivates people to do so? (Somehow I really really can't feel any urge to think anywhere near hitting Close reading a sloppy question. Downvote, maybe, but not close. He should get the hint by the two digits negative rating.)

Comment: You need to pick a better example to complain about voting. That's a horrible Stack Overflow question; the faster it gets closed, the better.

Comment: You are probably one of the people confusing SO for a generic "help" site. Stack Overflow does _not_ exist to help individual askers, SO aims to be a high quality knowledge repository of solutions to common programming problems. A question must be useful to a broader audience to fit that goal; the question you posted is not and IMO can never become useful to more people than OP. It's just another variant of "I have no idea what I'm doing" where the most useful thing is to _close the question_ and tell OP to _learn the basics language before asking questions on SO_.

Comment: Putting a question on hold is *exactly the right way to handle* questions where the OP may not be a native english speaker. If a post isn't clear and needs editing, the OP can do so while the post is on hold, and then when it is clear we can reopen it.

Comment: I just knew it, if it weren't that Meta does not affect reps, I probably wouldn't even ask about this :p. I think bad questions could be simply left to sink away with downvotes, without anyone giving a fuss about them: it is even easier to just close the browser tab if you see something horrible by your standards than voting to put it on hold. What does it accomplish anyway? Or those people here never were newcomers desperately needing help which no-one would even give directions for? I was. And I know what it is like, being on your own with only demands, and no support, for years.

Comment: @Jubatian It accomplishes stopping people filling up the site with crappy questions. Actually, it doesn't, as there are too many of them... which causes the actual experts to stop participating on SO because they're tired of wading through a load of crap like the example you posted in order to find actually interesting, well researched questions. That in turn is of course bad for the site. And SO is **not** for people "desperately needing help", it's for people having specific, narrow programming problems. "I have no idea what I'm doing" is not narrow in the slightest.

Comment: And to continue that last thought, most of these people dont't even "desperately need help", they just need to sit down and _learn_ for a while. There are thousands of resources on-and offline for learning programming; if somebody asks a question like the above they are just lazy and did not learn enough. If they have a learning deficiency or are otherwise unable to do so, too bad for them, but that's again out of the scope of SO. They would need personal tutoring, not a bit of advice on a specific problem.

Comment: OK, I understand this end of the story. However in the past, at university I got to experience that many times that some professors really don't give a flinch. I originally got to the uni by my achievements on a physics competition, and that nice "education" we received there successfully turned me away from this subject, being along the mass "somehow passing" for the 3rd time. If there are no proper courses, it is quite hard to even figure out where to begin. It also requires a whole lot of experience to learn to search: I continuously run in people having trouble with that even at my job.

Comment: What SO requires is a modicum of effort.  The more effort you put in, the more you get back.  If you don't put in any, don't expect to get any.

Comment: see also: [Are the hurried downvoters improving this community?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275709/839601)

Answer (score 40):

It sounds odd to say... but Stack Overflow is not for helping an individual user with a specific question. It isn't a tutoring service or a debugging service, or a code writing service. People do get helped along the way, but the ultimate goal is to be a repository of high quality programming questions and answers.

The question is simply a "how do write this program" and a list of requirements. There was no effort at all by the OP, and no idea where he was stuck. Answers would effectively teach him how to program, hence the too-broad close reason. It may not be a terrible question for the reasons you outlined, but it is a horrible **Stack Overflow question**, so anyone who answered it would only be encouraging more users to post horrible questions like that. It was downvoted and closed rightfully.

> (Somehow I really really can't feel any urge to think anywhere near hitting Close reading a sloppy question. Downvote, maybe, but not close, he should get the hint by the two digits negative rating)

To expand on your issue with downvoting rather than closing. Closing and downvoting are two completely different acts with different purposes. They sometimes overlap, but they don't have to. Closing means that question is off-topic or otherwise unsuitable for the site. Downvoting is an assessment of the quality of the question. You can have a good quality and/or useful question that is off-topic or is unsuitable for the site, and likewise you can have a poor quality question that is on-topic.

For example, *[Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033)* is closed, but it also has a +1479 score. It is closed because they question does not fit the guidelines of a good question on Stack Overflow (anymore, although it did at one time). It is highly upvoted because many users found it useful.

Closing is a signal to **the original poster** that the question needs work and the close reason (plus any comments) is there to help guide the user to improve the question to make it acceptable to the site.

Voting is a signal to **the community** that the question is worth reading or was otherwise a good question. Sure it does signal the poster because of the negative reputation points impact, but if the poster does not care about the reputation, only cares about getting an answer, then the downvotes only won't tell the poster anything when someone answers their question.

So your thoughts that downvoting should be enough and not closing is incorrect. It is the closing of the question that is the signal that the post needs to be improved.

Comment: Then point me the right direction, just *where* is an appropriate tutoring site, where I could point those who appear to have similar problems?

Comment: @Jubatian You'll be hard-pressed to find any kind of site where these kind of questions get any kind of proper help. Fact of the matter is - the internet is too cold and distant to be able to deal with things that require personal attention.