# Am I breaking the laws or are there trolls in our community?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I've made a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303036/how-to-develop-android-app-which-communicate-with-other-to-send-data-via-bluetoo)*, I've clicked the "post" button, the page has been reloaded and exactly 6 seconds later I already had a downvote, I mean, who downvoted my question didn't even have time to read it! The original question:

> **TITLE**: How to develop Android App which communicate with other to send data via bluetooth? Do I need 2 virtual machines running on my computer?
>
> I'm planning to develop an android app which will communicate 2
>   smartphones to send data between them. The point is, I've been
>   wondering about how to develop it since I only have 1 virtual machine
>   with android studio, so I don't really know how could I test and debug
>   the data system transfer.
>
> Do I need to use another VM software like Bluestacks and being
>   instaling the app each time I need to test/debug something? Does
>   Android studio allow me to have 2 virtual machines running at the same
>   time? Anyway, if yes, it probably will consume a lot of resources of
>   my machine.
>
> So what could I do?

I always take a lot of care when I post my questions in order to ask them properly, so when I get downvotes I assume that I've made something wrong and I want to know what did I do bad, at least like this I will have the chance to learn and make it better the next time.

So, is it my bad or just trolls? (it would be the first time that I hear about trolls here).

**UPDATE**: well, anyway, when people judge question should bear in mind that yes, this is an english site, but the most people here does not have english as mother tongue, so it could be so hard to write some questions  or even make ourselves understand in a few of words. Was my question short, clear and directly? Probably not. Was it understandable? I think yes.

*Link to question closed due to **massive** downvotes without any reasons or suggests about how could I improve it. I feel really sad about it, I thought this community had a constructive spirit. This thread can be closed. Thanks to people who helped me!

Comment: Why can't it be both?

Comment: Well, as I said, I've never seen trolls here, this community is awesomely moderated IMO. And if i didn't something wrong, please tell me what.

Comment: sometimes 6 seconds is enough.

Comment: SO is famous for its quick responses.  It is not like you gave the reader a hard time to read your question.  Trolls are easy to recognize, they make grunty noises.

Comment: If im being honest, after 7 words into your question I was already leaning towards the downvote button since it was starting to sound like those without research effort, the further down I went the more I wanted to since it becomes unclear what your actual question is. The only reason I haven't is because I don't like meta-voting

Comment: @Sayse, I've been searching, believe me, I always do it under the premise of "Everything what you need to ask, there is someone who has already asked it with high probability". Maybe I've not searched with the appropiate words, dunno, but I didn't find anything. Anyway, why is my question unclear? Criticize what you want, I really appreciate it, but say why or I won't be able to improve.

Comment: I don't think it deserves a downvote but when a question starts off with "how do I make an app to do x..." that's often a red flag that the question is going to be overly broad. You did narrow it down quite a bit in the body of your question but whoever downvoted you might not have read that far.

Comment: @codeMagic That's what I'm looking for, suggests and constructive criticism, so thank you so much, I will edit it.

Comment: It may just need rewording, try to get it down to only one question (and by extension, one question mark). Such as "from what I can tell I may need to run two vm's from AS but i'm not even sure this is possible and it will probably consume too many resources"

Comment: lol 'it would be the first time that I hear about trolls here' - you are member for today?

Comment: Upvoted because this question is a good effort to improve. Also, this question is much better formulated than the actual that we are discussing.

Comment: see also: [Why are people so fast hitting the downvote or close button on certain questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271947/why-are-people-so-fast-hitting-the-downvote-or-close-button-on-certain-questions)

Comment: You are missing the badge "Informed" which suggests that you should read the [tour] some time. This is substantiated by your use of the phrase "This thread can be closed" -- SO is not a forum and *we* cannot 'close' a thread.

Comment: @Drumnbass: I had a similar reaction to most of the commenters here when looking over your SO post, but there is a solid question lurking in there. I've [edited your question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30303036/2) in a way that I think removes all those problems and might let you get an answer. The title in particular was a red flag, but should be good now. I hope you find that useful.

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks, but somebody just deleted it. They didn't even give me the chance to edit it. This community.

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes it's easy to quickly tell that the question should be downvoted and OP *should* be enlightened on how they can improve their question.

Your title is vague, not specific and it's asking "how to develop..". After a quick glance (not more than 2 seconds) I can see that there's no code block (it's not mandatory, but asking "how to develop" without demonstrating knowledge is problematic).

Your question lacks of demonstrating research efforts, too broad and not clear, and these observations can be concluded very quickly.

General tip: Don't waste your time on thinking about every downvote you get. If you get massive downvotes, it's a quite a big indication that something needs to be improved, and in such cases you'll probably be told what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Your question was **too broad**, that is why it received downvotes and close votes. The first three words of your title *"How to develop..."* immediately gives off that "too broad" vibe, which may have attributed to people downvoting very quickly.

*"I want to do this, can I do it, how can I do it?"* questions are subjective, have a multitude of answers, and are a poor fit for our community. Figure out what you're going to do and start working on that. When you have **specific** problems, ask those.

Please also take some time to review the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for guidance on what types of questions you should and shouldn't ask.

Comment: Hmm wasn't my question specific? I assume that my english level is not enough to be able to ask professional and shortest questions in a perfect english, but I think that is enough clear what I don't know how to do. In fact, I've shared my question with a pair of friends, they've understood what do I need without any problem.

Comment: @Drumnbass You're missing the point of this answer. Your question was understandable, but it was too broad and not specific enough.

Comment: The problem isn't clarity, the problem is that there is **too much** ambiguity.

Comment: If Android Studio only provides me 1 VM, how to test/debug an android app which needs 2 devices to work. I don't know how to be more specific.