# Time between a post is marked as a possible duplicate and is deemed fit for closing

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[One of my posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299732/a-stack-site-for-asking-broad-open-ended-questions#comment222911_299732) was just marked as duplicate. For a brief moment I saw a banner on top of my post saying "possible duplicate of" and below that was two options one that said "This answered my question" and another that said "I will edit my question" (or something to that effect). This banner quickly went away. I am assuming this happened when the post got enough "close" votes.

I have seen this feature for the first time. I did not get a chance to use it on this post . Whats the idea behind having this? Is it that small window to edit your post and prevent it from being closed or maybe to "close" it yourself , if the possible duplicate link had an answer to your original post.

Comment: Related on MSE: [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes)

Comment: It allows you to agree that the duplicate answers your question. When you do this (as the person who asked the question) it closes immediately and no further close votes. If you don't agree you are able to edit the question and say why you think it is not a duplicate. Depending on how many people are looking at the question it may get closed before you can action it, as you noticed.

Comment: related (_not_ a duplicate): [Why are people so fast hitting the downvote or close button on certain questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271950/839601)

Comment: feature allowing asker to singlehandedly close their question as duplicate is actually only 3-4 months old. That close of your question here went _that_ fast is because it's often repeated here and because close voters here are very active

Comment: @DavidPostill: Of course you still can edit the closed question, which will make it go to the reopen queue.