# Why are questions on the Spring framework closed so quickly?

Tags: support, flags, downvotes

I don't wan't to trash anyone or neither create a debate, but I am tired re asking the same question without getting any answer and losing any possibility to get an answer for that.

I am surprised how fast my questions get closed or voted down when it come to Spring.

It doesn't generally take longer than two days.

They generally invoke that the question has already been answered before.

I have check and it does not. I am surprised of the efficiency they have for this task.

Is it normal that they can close a question that has not been answered before?

*NB: I know you will all want to know what is the question, it is not the topic of this question but I will write it down here so we can get to the point:*

*I want to know if spring-security and spring-security-oauth2 can secure a single endpoint. So far, I only see a route secured by one or the other. Of course both plugin can work on the same project.*

Comment: i mean, yeah, it's possible members from <insert certain community> are moderating questions on SO. They have the same opportunity as anyone else to build up reputation here.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe the problem is with the questions, not the moderation actions happening against them?

Comment: Why did you put "meta stack exchange" in your question? [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) is a Meta site for the entire network, it has nothing to do with your questions on Stack Overflow being downvoted/closed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907425/two-layer-of-security-for-one-endpoint-using-spring-security-and-spring-security The question.

Comment: Sorry for being a bad guy, but this question most surely is a duplicate too :(

Comment: Currently there is one close vote : no MVCE, your post must be self contained and not rely on external sources that will probably die one day.

Comment: Reasking the same question over and over again is a good path toward getting a question ban. Note that if your question is being closed as a duplicate, the message that appears on the question details what to do. Namely, edit the (original) question with details on how the duplicate question(s) does not answer your question.

Comment: In the past 30 days, you've asked 22 questions. Of those, 3 have been closed (2 as duplicates, one as a tool recommendation). 7 have been upvoted, 3 downvoted. You've self-deleted 8 of these. Generally, your questions have been well-received, so I'm not sure I see the same negative trend you do.

Comment: *Why are questions on the Spring framework closed so quickly?* because we are damn good at that...

Comment: Votes on meta don't affect your reputation. You can't get a normal question ban here.

Comment: You should not be vandalizing your questions.

Comment: @BigDong Questions are closed when they meet criteria for closure, not when you just want them to be closed.

Comment: @Servy understood. Enjoy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are people so fast hitting the downvote or close button on certain questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271947/why-are-people-so-fast-hitting-the-downvote-or-close-button-on-certain-questions)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Over the past 90 days, a bit over 7% of [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) questions were closed. That's a bit lower than the average for the site as a whole.

42% of those questions were closed as duplicates. That's a bit higher than the average for the site as a whole.

There's a reasonably good chance here that quite a few askers are inexperienced, both in terms of Spring Framework itself and in terms of asking questions here. That leads to poorly-written (unclear / overly-broad) questions and questions which have already been asked many times before. This is not an uncommon set of problems.

Directing new askers to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) would be a kindness.

Comment: This user has 101 questions and we're talking about his questions, surely he get redirected to that more than once.

Comment: As Brad mentioned, this user's questions don't really exhibit the problem he's describing. So, worth sanity-checking the generalizations.